# TypeScript read pop3 email

Tags: typescript, pop3

I recently started working with TypeScript and am working on an application to read pop3 emails.  I came across a pop3 library/service called Nylas and used one of their examples.  When I try to build the app with tsc I get the following error in the "then" section.  I don't know enough about TypeScript/Javascript to get around it though:

error TS7006: Parameter 'threads' implicitly has an 'any' type.

And here's my code example:

```
import { Email, IEmail } from "./domain/Email"

import Nylas from "nylas";

const CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';
const ACCESS_TOKEN = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';

Nylas.config({
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
});
 
const nylas = Nylas.with(ACCESS_TOKEN);

 // List the 5 most recent unread email threads and print their subject lines
nylas.threads.list({unread: true, limit: 5}).then(threads =>{
  for (let thread of threads) {
      console.log(thread.subject);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing nylas as a raw module, which gives it the `any` type.

You should import it like so:

```
import Nylas from "nylas";
```

You probably wrote `require('nylas')` because `import * as Nylas from "nylas";` does not work. This is because nylas uses `module.exports =`, instead of `export default` (it doesn't use ES6 style exports).

You can read more about default exports and the different types of import statements here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export .

Comment: That helped a lot.  I now receive the following error: error TS2339: Property 'subject' does not exist on type 'RestfulModel'.

Comment: It might work if you use `thread.attributes()["subject"]` instead, but I am not familiar with Nylas enough to know. If that doesn't work, you might have more luck by opening a new question, as that errors looks like that error is more related to Nylas itself, instead of with TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @yeerk.  I think you may be right though.  I need some Nylas support.  I tried your comment above and it did build but the console output was not what I expected.  But I did learn some important points on the way.

Comment: No problem @user1572, happy to assist! If my answer solved your question, would you consider marking it as the correct answer?